# EmberJS and Jquery Mobile gives blank grey page

Tags: jquery-mobile, ember.js

I am trying to build a small mobile app with JQuery Mobile and EmberJS.
This is actually a Rhodes Application (Rhomobile).

This is my Layout.erb:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

    <title>Todo</title>


        <!-- Ember Libraries -->        
        <script src="/public/js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
        <script src="/public/js/libs/ember.js"></script>
        <script src="/public/js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>

        <!-- Ember Application -->
        <script src="/public/js/application.js"></script>
        <script src="/public/js/router.js"></script>
        <script src="/public/js/models/todo.js"></script>
        <script src="/public/js/controllers/todos_controller.js"></script>




        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){    
                $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
                $.mobile.loadingMessageDelay = 300; // in ms
                $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
                $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
                $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
                $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
                $.mobile.loadingMessageDelay = 50; // in ms
            });
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/jqmobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/jqmobile-patch.css">
        <script src="/public/jqmobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/public/js/jqmobile-patch.js"></script>

</head>

<body data-platform="<%= Rho::System.getProperty('platform') %>">
    <%= @content %>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see I have disabled Ajax and PushState and stuff. This is my index.erb:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos">
    <div data-role="page">
        //My Template
      </div>
  </script>
```

Now when I try it, I just get a blank grey page. But no error in console or in Ember-Console (extension of Chrome). It even detects my views and controllers properly.

Then I try commenting the JqueryMobile CSS files and what I get is a page's height worth of blank space with "Loading" message and then I see my application below and it works fine. And if I remove JqueryMobile JS, I get the stuff but its not styled.

What is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make jQuery Mobile stop breaking Ember.js site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617480/how-to-make-jquery-mobile-stop-breaking-ember-js-site)

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to say without seeing some more code of your app.  If you only have the one template defined (`'todos'`) it may be the case that Ember doesn't know how to kickstart the rendering of your app.  You may need to define an `'application'` template.  It might be as simple as:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes I do have only one template. Could that be the problem? Why doesnt the todos mvc app have this template?

Comment: Very hard to say without seeing any code.  Can you post a JSBin?