# Any working examples of jQuery Mobile + ember.js?

Tags: jquery-mobile, ember.js

I see many examples ([such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857247/can-i-use-jquery-mobile-with-emberjs)) of it, but no one is worked for latest versions of ember and jqm. Any suggestions?

[jqm - 1.3.2](http://jquerymobile.com/download/)

[ember.js - 1.1.2](http://emberjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this yesterday: [How to make jQuery Mobile stop breaking Ember.js site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617480/how-to-make-jquery-mobile-stop-breaking-ember-js-site/19619893#19619893)

Essentially the hash location of emberjs needs to be disabled or the hash location of jquery mobile needs to be.

Comment: In your solution jqm elements, like buttons is not working(styles for example) [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/Ubatiri/3/).

Comment: I didn't include the css.

Comment: your solution is work, but for using jqm widgets needs this hack in views:  didInsertElement:function(){
    this.$().trigger('create');
    }